# Document constraints in JSDoc

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3, jsdoc2md

I have a function which is a React component. The element it creates has `position:absolute;` In order for this property to work in a predictable way the parent element should be positioned with `position: relatieve;`. I would like to let future users of this component to know about this constraint. Is there a JSDoc tag for such a purpose? How would you let users of this component know about this important constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to highlight that your component has a run-time dependency on a particular external state. There is no specific jsdoc tag for this, you'd need to document it in the description.

In jsdoc2md you can declare any arbitrary tag, if that helps - you could invent your own tag to document it.

Custom tag example:

```js
/**
 * This function has a wonderful custom tag
 * @createdIn Nigeria
 */
function customTaggedFunction () {}
```

Produces this output:

### customTaggedFunction()

This function has a wonderful custom tag

**Kind**: global function
**Createdin**: Nigeria